# TYPO3 - Own upgrade wizard: INSERT with SELECT from other table

Tags: php, mysql, typo3, extbase

I'm trying to write my first TYPO3 (9.5) Upgrade Wizard. It's for one of my own extensions, where I want to extract uids to build a, now new, mm-table.

Basically, I need to build a query that matches a mysql statement like

```
INSERT INTO tx_myextension_table1_table2_mm (uid_local, uid_foreign) 
SELECT uid, field1 
FROM tx_myextension_domain_model_table1 
WHERE field1 > 0;
```

Since I don't seem to have access to a repository when I'm including it the same way as in the controller, I can't use the createQuery() function.

I'm really struggling to build this statement with the ConnectionPool classes - the insert and bulkInsert seem to be far too simple for such case - or the QueryBuilder.

Comment: are those two different queries? Do you first need to populate the mm table and then you want to select the uid & field1 from table1?

Comment: It's one single query. In the old model 'field1' is a single foreign key in form of the uid of table2. In the new model it is possible to select multiple records from table2. To make the old versions run after the update I have to extract the value (if it exists -> 'Where field1 >0) to the field uid_foreign in the new mm table and the uid of the table1 record to the field uid_local. That's what this query does, but I need to achieve this within the possibilities of TYPO3, since createQuery is not not usable in the wizard. (In a second step I update the old field1, but that's not the problem)

Comment: why not? can you not instantiate the Repository?

Comment: I don't know how at this point.
If I try to use it the same way as in the controller
```
/**
 * exampleRepository
 *
 * @var \Vendor\Myextension\Domain\Repository\ExampleRepository
 * @inject
 */
protected $exampleRepository = NULL;
```
The wizard throws me an error saying, that $exampleRepository is null. Maybe it's the missing functionality of the ActionController that takes care of the part of filling the repository?